# Square payments multiple sellers and payments in parallel

Tags: square

I need some help with Square Payments. I'm trying to sell products online through the website I'm developing and there are multiple sellers who sell there. Those sellers have their own logins and they can connect to the Square Payments from their login portal and add their products.

Now a buyer can add multiple products from different sellers in during order completion payment will be distributed to sellers accordingly.

But, I'm not able to find any APIs or anything in Square Payments which can help me to achieve this.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not entirely feasible. In order for your application to call Square APIs on merchant's behalf, you would need to utilize the [OAuth API](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/oauth-api/what-it-does). However, if the customer/buyer will be purchasing products from various merchants, you would need to make multiple calls to [CreatePayment](https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/payments-api/create-payment)...and each time, have a unique `nonce`. This means, the customer would need to fill our their card number for each merchant they're buying from, since cards are stored at a merchant-scope (not application-scope). So while it could be done, it would not be a very good customer experience unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you so much @sjosey.

You're right. Maybe I need to look for alternatives. then.